# Strange ASP.NET issue when trying to find value contained in a TextBox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have a form with a number of asp:TextBoxes. The user is able to edit the text within these text boxes, and when the 'SAVE' button is pressed, these new values are written to a database.

I have 3 text boxes in total, and the first 2 text boxes' new values are passed on to the code behind without any problem. However, the 3rd text box's old content is passed onto the server, rather than the user-edited data.

The markup for the problematic textbox is shown below:

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="descriptionBox" ReadOnly="true" style" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

The following is the C# code which attempts to get the contents of the text box after the user has edited it. Please note that these text boxes are placed in a Repeater:

```
string description = ((TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("descriptionBox")).Text;
```

Could anyone suggest what the problem could be? The other text boxes use the same exact markup and code, and they work just fine.

Comment: Why is it marked with "ReadOnly" if you want it to be changed?

Comment: Does your markup really include `style"` or is that a typo?

Comment: The reason it's marked readonly is because I want it to be uneditable when it's first loaded. That propery is then changed with jQuery in later code, as a result of a button click event. The solution was to set this attribute through javascript rather than ASP :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.readonly.aspx) - it's the ReadOnly attribute causing this problem:

> The Text value of a TextBox control with the ReadOnly property set to
>   true is sent to the server when a postback occurs, but the server does
>   no processing for a read-only text box.

The alternative is to do it on the client side:

`descriptionBox.Attributes["readonly"] = "readonly"`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is because you have the following property on the TextBox: ReadOnly="True"!

**Edit:**
Was too late, credits go to Pointy who answered as a comment.. :)

Comment: Well I don't know ASP so I couldn't answer :-)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem :)